# no stereo audio in speakers and in one earphone using waveout

Tags: waveout

I have written an application using MSoft WaveOut api and it works fine except that my speakers don't play stereo only mono.  When I plug an earphone in one of the two jacks in one I get the same mono behavior but the other jack plays the file in stereo.  If I use something that uses DirectX api, all plays in stereo.
My equipment is Dell Studio XP.
Can someone suggest a reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

you shold change Channels parameter from 1 to 2

```
format.wFormatTag = 1 ' PCM
format.nChannels = 1 '1=mono   ,  2=Steero <<<<<<
format.nSamplesPerSec = 8000 ' 12000
format.wBitsPerSample = 16
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the volume.  I was setting the volume with code like:

```
unsigned long x = 0xFFFF;
MMRESULT result = waveOutSetVolume( _audio_device, x );
```

when in fact, I needed to do:

```
unsigned short left = unsigned(0xFFFF * v);
unsigned short right = unsigned(0xFFFF * v);

unsigned long x = left + (right << 16);
MMRESULT result = waveOutSetVolume( _audio_device, x );
```